# Date object with multiple variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, react-hooks, jsx

I'm on React and I'm just trying to display the time passing (hours) with my `useState` and `useEffect` to update my state. Until here no problem, but below you can see I'm using another Date object. The problem is that when I'm using it in my `JSX‍` every value is updated when I just want to update my state `time`.
What is the problem? Any idea?

```
const [time, setTime] = useState((''))

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTime(prevState => new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);

const now = new Date();
const dateString = now.toLocaleDateString();
const dateStringTime = now.toLocaleTimeString();
const isoString = now.toISOString();

const milliSec = now.getTime();
const annee = now.getFullYear();
const month = now.getMonth();
const jourMois = now.getDate();
const seconds = now.getSeconds();
const minutes = now.getMinutes();
const heure = now.getHours();
```

I tried many combinations and searched on the internet, but no answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Based on your code you have a state `time`, every second you update it with a new string representing the current time value. What is the behaviour you want to achieve?

Comment: To be more clear : my state time is updated every. second by setInterval, but strangely the variable `millisec` for example is also updated. Every seconds I can see these variable changing in my render. `seconds` is changing too, minutes also after some times...
But `now` is another objet so I really not understand why they are both updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly:

The second const date `now` gets updated every time the page renders. So both "time" variable get updated.

One solution could be to both store them in a state.

```
const [time, setTime] = useState('')
const [secondTime, setSecondTime] = useState('')
```

And then set the second date during the useEffect.

```
const now = new Date();
    useEffect(() => {
        setSecondTime(now);
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setTime(prevState => new Date().toLocaleTimeString())
        }, 1000);

        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);
```

Does that help/answer your question?

Comment: Ok you are completely right it's working !
Thank you very much, really useful !